# Unable to connect AKS cluster: connection time out

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-container-service

I've created an AKS cluster in the UK region in Azure.

Currently, I can no longer access my AKS cluster. Connecting to the public IPs fails; all connections time out.

Furthermore, I can't run the `kubectl` command either:

`fcarlier@ubuntu:~$ kubectl get nodes
 Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout`

Is there a known issue with AKS in that region or is it something on my side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a known issue with AKS in that region or is it something on
>   my side?

Sorry to give you a bad experience.
For now, Azure AKS still in preview, please try to **recreate** it, ukwest works fine now.

Here is a similar [case](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/14) about you, please refer to it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately recreating the cluster in the ukwest region doesn't work. I'm seeing the same behavior as described [in the case](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/14#issuecomment-343471598). 

Provisioning in westus2 doesn't work either:

"Azure Container Service is unable to provision an AKS cluster in westus2, due to an operational threshold."

Comment: @FrederikCarlier Thank you for your feedback, Microsoft engineering teams are trying to fix it, your understanding and support will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Jason Ye - MSFT just got this error. happened after I did the upgrade command
az aks upgrade -n xxxxTestCluster -g xxxxTestResourceGroup -k 1.8.1

Answer (score 0):

I just successfully created a single node AKS cluster on UK West with no issues. Can you please retest? For now, I would avoid provisioning on West US 2 until the threshold issues are fixed. I'm aware the AKS team is actively engaged to restore service on West US. Sorry for the inconvenience. Below is the sample cmd to create in UK if you need the reference. Hope this helps.

1. Create Resource Group (UK West):az group create --name myResourceGroupUK --location ukwest
2. Create AKS cluster in (UK west):az aks create --resource-group myResourceGroupUK --name myK8sClusterUK --agent-count 1 --generate-ssh-keys

Comment: what `threshold` issues are you refering to?

Comment: I always get this issue creating an aks cluster in ukwest.  The VM size of Agent is not allowed in your subscription in location 'ukwest'. Agent VM size 'Standard_D2_v2' is available in locations: centraluseuap,eastus,eastus2,eastus2euap,koreacentral,koreasouth,southcentralus,southeastasia,westcentralus,westeurope,westus2.

Comment: Provisioning in UK West still doesn't work; you can create a new cluster but if you run `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` you'll see that the cluster is unhealthy. If you leave it running for a couple of hours you'll be unable to connect to the cluster. What is your output for `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` for your cluster?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. According to the GitHub update, ukwest is also hitting an outage. To mitigate the issue, a new provisioning service has been spun up in East US. I recommend creating a new AKS cluster in East US and ping me if errors/issues persist.

Comment: Just found this official update from the AKS service team that as of 6 hrs ago, service was restored to ukwest. Get the latest outage updates from https://github.com/Azure/AKS/blob/master/annoucements/service_outage_2017-11-09.md

Answer (score 0):

I just finished a big post over here on this topic (which is not as straight forward as a single solution / workaround): ['Unable to connect Net/http: TLS handshake timeout' — Why can't Kubectl connect to Azure Kubernetes server? (AKS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50726534/unable-to-connect-net-http-tls-handshake-timeout-why-cant-kubectl-connect)

That being said, the solution to this one for me was to scale the nodes up — and then back down — for my impacted Cluster from the Azure Kubernetes service blade web console.

## Workaround / Potential Solution

1. Log into the Azure Console — Kubernetes Service blade.
2. Scale your cluster up by 1 node.
3. Wait for scale to complete and attempt to connect (you should be able to).
4. Scale your cluster back down to the normal size to avoid cost increases.

Total time it took me ~2 mins.

### More Background Info on the Issue

Also added this solution to the full ticket description write up that I posted over here (if you want more info have a read):

['Unable to connect Net/http: TLS handshake timeout' — Why can't Kubectl connect to Azure Kubernetes server? (AKS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50726534/unable-to-connect-net-http-tls-handshake-timeout-why-cant-kubectl-connect)